# "file does not exist" error after pip install file_name.whl (pygame 1.9.4)

Tags: python-2.7

When I typed `pip install file_name.whl` after installing the pygame 1.9.4 for python 2.7.9 in command prompt of windows 10 32 bit laptop, it displayed file does not exist. What should I do?

Comment: are you in the correct location ?

Comment: If not , give the absolute path , example `pip install C:/some-dir/file.whl`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing with absolute path and you should be able to get it working

```
pip install C:/some-dir/file.whl
```

Comment: it is again showing does not exist. Please say the complete procedure about this.

Comment: Also check if you have opened the command promt as ADMINISTRATOR

Comment: And if you still have some crazy issye with pip, try `python -m pip install C:/some-dir/file.wh`